# what does this symbol mean (like a perpendicular symbol, in set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation

Sent from my phone so have pity on me (long train journey)

Azriel Levy basic set theory, Dover, p13

What does the symbol after the P* mean in 4.5?

Will edit in picture. Mobile mode doesn't have it.

Okay I have an answer. I will add the picture when I get home.

Thanks for not closing - I appreciate it!

Comment: How about you wait with posting the question until you can post something that makes sense?

Comment: @johanna I will Gondor easiest to type on a phone. I have an answer anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(As the book happens to be within arm's reach as I listen to music ...)

It's the standard turnstile symbol '$\vdash$' for (syntactic) entailment.

So e.g., to simplify Levy's example, $P \vdash A \leftrightarrow B$ says that in (the theory) $P$ we can derive $A \leftrightarrow B$

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate this. I will tick later.